# Unit test and code coverage on EventHandlers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, eventhandler

I'm trying to do a unit test on the eventHandler in the class and I'm not exactly sure how to get valid data to put in the tests. Thanks in advance!

```
public class BriefAssociation
    {

        public static event EventHandler<AssociationEventArgs> BriefAssociationChanged;
        public static event EventHandler<AssociationEventArgs> BriefAssociationChangedEvent;

        public static void OnBriefAssociationChanged(AssociationEventArgs e)
        {
            BriefAssociationChanged(null, e);
        }

        public static bool HasListener(EventHandler<AssociationEventArgs> TestCheck)
        {
            if ((BriefAssociationChangedEvent != null))
                if ((BriefAssociationChangedEvent.GetInvocationList().Length > 0))
                {
                    return true;
                }

            return false;
        }
    }


    public class AssociationEventArgs
    { 
        public int CustomerID;
    }
```

**CHANGES** The following edit is for an error which is discussed in the comments

```
public class BriefAssociation
{

    public static event EventHandler<AssociationEventArg> BriefAssociationChanged;
    public static event EventHandler<AssociationEventArg> BriefAssociationChangedEvent;

    public static void OnBriefAssociationChanged(AssociationEventArg e)
    {
        BriefAssociationChanged(null, e);
    }


    public static bool HasListener(EventHandler<AssociationEventArg> TestCheck)
    {
        if ((BriefAssociationChangedEvent != null))
            if ((BriefAssociationChangedEvent.GetInvocationList().Length > 0))
            {
                return true;
            }

        return false;
    }
}
public class AssociationEventArg
{ 
    public int CustomerID;
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in testing how the event is being handled or fired? Have you tried using a mocking framework?

Comment: I thought of mocking but can't wrap my head around it yet , so that's why I asked to see if there is another way of doing it. @IgorMeszaros

Comment: I'm trying to understand what do you want to test here? Do you want to see that OnBriefAssociationChanged will raise BriefAssociationChanged event with certain arguments? The name of the method makes it sound like it is a event handler, is that true?

Comment: Yes you understand it correctly. I'm not sure how give it valid arguments to see if it works. For the second method "HasListener" I have a test that gives it a null value to test the if statement but I need to give it something that has a value of  length grater than 0 to test the rest of the function. I hope it makes sense.  @IgorMeszaros

Comment: To be honest I never used a method that takes an event handler as an input parameter. But it would be a different discussion to figure out why was that done. for the OnBriefAssociationChanged I can provide a simple test that you could use, if you're interested.

Comment: That would be great thank you @IgorMeszaros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the second method "HasListener" I have a test that gives it a null value to test the if statement but I need to give it something that has a value of length grater than 0 to test the rest of the function. I hope it makes sense.

This is a simple test that might help

```
[Test]
public void should_raise_event()
{
    BriefAssociation.BriefAssociationChangedEvent += BriefAssociationChanged;
    bool result = BriefAssociation.HasListener(null);
    Assert.True(result);
}

public void BriefAssociationChanged(Object obj, AssociationEventArgs associationEventArgs)
{ }
```

Comment: `Error CS0123 No overload for 'BriefAssociationChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler<AssociationEventArg>' `
After the project was updateded by the rest of the team , something broke the test you wrote. Any ideas what can it be?

Comment: sounds like they've changed the signature of the events. Have a look at how they define `BriefAssociationChangedEvent` now. what does the BriefAssociation class look like now?

Comment: I've put the exact code that is at the moment. I am not sure what is changed or why does it throws and error now but I am 100% sure that it worked when you posted.

Comment: The only change i can see `AssociationEventArgs` type name has changed to `AssociationEventArg`. So you need to update the fake method `BriefAssociationChanged` parameter to use the new type name

Answer (score 1):

Here's all the test you need for the 1st method:

```
    [Test]
    public void OnBriefAssociationCHanged_ShouldRaiseBriefAssociationChangedEvent()
    {
        // Data
        object resultSender = null;
        AssociationEventArgs resultArgs = null;
        AssociationEventArgs testArgs = new AssociationEventArgs();

        // Setup
        BriefAssociation.BriefAssociationChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            resultSender = sender;
            resultArgs = args;
        };

        // Test
        BriefAssociation.OnBriefAssociationChanged(testArgs);

        // Analysis
        Assert.IsNull(resultSender);
        Assert.AreSame(resultArgs, testArgs);
    }
```